# MapReduce with phoenix : org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, apache-phoenix

I am trying to insert values into a table ("mea_interval") from data collected in another table ("mea_data"). The idea is not unique, it identifies a datatype.  I use MeasureWritable class to read and write to the database, it implements DBWritable and Writable. When I run my jar I get the error:

```
15/12/15 10:13:38 WARN mapred.LocalJobRunner: job_local957174264_0001
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable
        at org.apache.phoenix.mapreduce.PhoenixRecordWriter.write(PhoenixRecordWriter.java:39)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask$NewTrackingRecordWriter.write(ReduceTask.java:551)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.TaskInputOutputContextImpl.write(TaskInputOutputContextImpl.java:85)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.reduce.WrappedReducer$Context.write(WrappedReducer.java:99)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.reduce(Reducer.java:144)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:164)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:610)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:444)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:449))
```

I can read the values in the table mea_data. If I display in console, they appear good. I think the error occurs during the execution of context.write in the map but I don't understand why.

I attached you the code of the job configuration and my map class. If you want to see another part of my code do not hesitate.

Thank you beforehand. :)

The job configuration :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableMapReduceUtil;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;

import org.apache.phoenix.mapreduce.PhoenixInputFormat;
import org.apache.phoenix.mapreduce.PhoenixOutputFormat;
import org.apache.phoenix.mapreduce.util.PhoenixConfigurationUtil;
import org.apache.phoenix.mapreduce.util.PhoenixMapReduceUtil;

public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Configuration configuration = HBaseConfiguration.create();
        final Job job;
        try {
            job = Job.getInstance(configuration, "phoenix-mr-job");
            final String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM \"mea_data\" where \"timestamp\" > 1450168200";
            PhoenixMapReduceUtil.setInput(job, MeasureWritable.class, "mea_data",     selectQuery);

            // Set the target Phoenix table and the columns
            PhoenixMapReduceUtil.setOutput(job, "\"mea_interval\"", "id_collection,startDate,endDate,value");

            job.setMapperClass(MeasureMapper.class);
            job.setReducerClass(MeasureReducer.class);

            job.setOutputFormatClass(PhoenixOutputFormat.class);
            // job.setInputFormatClass(PhoenixInputFormat.class);
            job.setNumReduceTasks(10);
            job.setMapOutputKeyClass(LongWritable.class);
            job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
            job.setOutputKeyClass(NullWritable.class);
            job.setOutputValueClass(MeasureWritable.class);

            // TableMapReduceUtil.addDependencyJars(job);
            job.waitForCompletion(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The mapper class :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;

public class MeasureMapper extends Mapper<NullWritable , MeasureWritable, LongWritable, Text> {

    @Override
    protected void map(NullWritable key, MeasureWritable measureWritable, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        final long timestamp = measureWritable.getTimestamp();
        double val = measureWritable.getValue();
        final long id = measureWritable.getId();
        System.out.print("id : "+ new LongWritable(id));
        System.out.print(" timestamp : "+ timestamp);
        System.out.println(" val : "+ val);
        try{
            context.write(new LongWritable(id), new Text(timestamp + ";" + val));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The reducer class :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;

public class MeasureReducer extends Reducer<LongWritable, Iterable<Text>, NullWritable, MeasureWritable> {

    protected void reduce(LongWritable key, Iterable<Text> valeurs, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        MeasureWritable interval = new MeasureWritable();
        interval.setId(Long.valueOf(key.toString()).longValue());
        NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();
        for(Text valeur : valeurs) {
            String[] array = valeur.toString().split(";", -1);
            interval.setStartingDate(Long.valueOf(array[0]).longValue());
            interval.setEndingDate(Long.valueOf(array[0]).longValue());
            try {
                interval.setValue(nf.parse(array[1]).doubleValue() );
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        context.write(NullWritable.get(), interval);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your reducer code? That is where the error is.

Comment: It's done, I added the reducer in my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use LongWritable as Mapper's input key as well as map method's first parameter instead of NullWritable.

Comment: I already tried. I get the following error:
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable

Comment: I based on the following code: https://phoenix.apache.org/phoenix_mr.html is that's why I put NullWritable.

Comment: Please check the following link, https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PHOENIX-1868  it might help you.

Comment: Thank you very much, it helped me a lot. It's impossible to put a type Text in the output value of the map class.

Comment: Can you uncomment  `job.setInputFormatClass(PhoenixInputFormat.class); ` line in your code and try?

Comment: Thanks to your previous comment my code works. If I uncommented this line that changes nothing.